# Debian 404 The request url not found on this server

Tags: php, linux, apache, debian, http-status-code-404

I'm new to linux environment. I have installed debian os and apache2 server. I have been doing a code igniter project. My problem is, I'm able to render index file in code igniter. But If I go into inner pages like localhost/login or localhost/register I get this

```
The requested url not found on this server
```

error. How to over come this?

This is my apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Answer (score 2):

Enable the apache2 modmule "mod_rewrite" with

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

After that, allow for you directory to overwrite rules for this module with

```
AllowOverride FileInfo
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't use CodeIgniter, but from what I know of it, I expect it uses mod rewrite in .htaccess, which means your `<Directory />` and `<Directory /var/www/>` should be `AllowOverride All`.  You may also need to `a2enmod rewrite` at the command line.

Comment: Changing Allowoverride None to Allowoverride All did the trick. Thanks :)

Comment: Don't use the keyword "All" ! Everytime allow only the things you really need!